# assimp invalid enumerant IL_JPG OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos, parsing, devil

I built DevIL on OSX. I can load in certain files like targa and bitmap, maybe others. There are, however, many files that cannot be parsed in or saved out. The *error message* given is that of an `invalid enumrant`. Has anybody come across such an error?

Comment: Are you sure it's *supposed* to work on OS X and/or with recent version of libraries it depends on? (DevIL hasn't been updated in 4.5 years - have you checked out ResIL, which is a maintained fork?)

Comment: ... and a quick test of this new thing called Goggle or something - it magically looks for things online for you! - suggests that quite a few people have indeed come across that error through the years.